# How to display different directories on different QTabWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtabwidget

I can't run more than one function to set layout to different tabs.

In my code only the last **def** function runs even if i interchange their position still its only the last **def** that runs.

I tried adding another function to check (**def_one**) and it works and still only one (the last) tab function runs.

here is my code.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
import os
import shutil


import DiskCleaner_ui


class main(QMainWindow, DiskCleaner_ui.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)


        systray_icon = QIcon("s.png")
        self.systray = QSystemTrayIcon(systray_icon, self)

        menu = QMenu()
        restore = QAction("Restore", self)
        close = QAction("Close", self)

        menu.addActions([restore, close])
        self.systray.setContextMenu(menu)

        self.systray.show()
        self.systray.showMessage("DC", "Started...", QSystemTrayIcon.Information)

        close.triggered.connect(self.close)

        self.treeView = QTreeView()
        self.fileSystemModel = QFileSystemModel(self.treeView)
        self.fileSystemModel.setReadOnly(False)
        self.root = self.fileSystemModel.setRootPath(r'C:\Users\Black Laptop\Desktop')
        self.treeView.setModel(self.fileSystemModel)
        self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.root)
        self.treeView.setSortingEnabled(True)

        self.Delete_Button = QPushButton("Clear Files")
        self.Delete_Button.setFixedSize(90, 30)

        self.Layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.Layout.addWidget(self.treeView)
        self.Layout.addWidget(self.Delete_Button)

        self.Duplicate() #doesnt run
        self.Unused()    #doesnt run
        self.Temp() #last position : runs (even if i interchange functions between them
        self.one()# to check : runs



    def Temp(self):
        self.Temp_Tab.setLayout(self.Layout)
        self.Delete_Button.clicked.connect(self.Clear_Temp_Files)

    def Duplicate(self):
        self.Duplicate_Tab.setLayout(self.Layout)

    def Unused(self):
        self.UnUsed_Tab.setLayout(self.Layout)

    def one(self):
        print('self.one() works...')


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Exit', "Are you sure you want to exit?", QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()



    def scan(self):
        if os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Black Laptop\Desktop\Py1') == []:
            self.systray.showMessage("DC", "Empty...", QSystemTrayIcon.Information)
        else:
            return


    def Clear_Temp_Files(self):
        self.scan()
        with os.scandir(r'C:\Users\Black Laptop\Desktop\Py1') as entries:
            for entry in entries:
                if entry.is_file() or entry.is_symlink():
                    os.remove(entry.path)
                    self.systray.showMessage("DC", "Temporary files/folders cleared", QSystemTrayIcon.Information)
                elif entry.is_dir():
                    shutil.rmtree(entry.path)
                    self.systray.showMessage("DC", "Temporary files/folders cleared", QSystemTrayIcon.Information)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    H = main()
    H.show()
    app.exec_()
```

here is the  DiskCleaner_ui

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'DiskCleaner.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.10.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(594, 341)
        #MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(81, 81, 81);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(189, 189, 189);\n"
"alternate-background-color: rgb(44, 44, 44);\n"
"border-color: rgb(185, 185, 185);")
        self.tabWidget.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.Temp_Tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Temp_Tab.setObjectName("Temp_Tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.Temp_Tab, "")
        self.Duplicate_Tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.Duplicate_Tab.setObjectName("Duplicate_Tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.Duplicate_Tab, "")

        self.UnUsed_Tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.UnUsed_Tab.setObjectName("UnUsed_Tab")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.UnUsed_Tab, "")


        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Disk Cleaner"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.Temp_Tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Temp Files"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabToolTip(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.Temp_Tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Temporary files..."))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.Duplicate_Tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Duplicate files"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabToolTip(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.Duplicate_Tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Duplicate Files..."))

        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.UnUsed_Tab), _translate("MainWindow", "UnUsed files"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabToolTip(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.UnUsed_Tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Unused Files for a peeriod of time..."))
```

thanks...

Comment: so how do i go about it...am i to create different layout for each Tab....?

Comment: yes....is there anyway to go about it..?

Comment: @eyllanesc....pls how do i access folders on other computers when the app is installed on other systems...?

Comment: Is there a way in python...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around by creating new FileSystemModel and Root for each tab